# From 1 to N, print all the pairs of number that has sum larger than 50

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm new to Java and I have an exercise like this. From 1 to N, print all the pairs of number that has sum larger than 50.
For example if N = 60, then the result will be something like (1,50);(1,51);...;(1,60);...;(2,49);(2,50);...;(2,60);....;(58,59);(58,60);(59,60). I'm thinking about some nested while loop with a run from 1 to N and b run from N to 1, then the condition is a+b>50. I think if a+b<50 it will be easier since I can set b = 50-a or something like that. Still I'm quite of confusing right now.

Comment: You'r on the right track, you need two loops. For a start, you can let both loops run until N. Just attempt to code something, it will become clearer with existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = 60;
        for (int i=1; i<=N; i++) {          //1st loop
            for (int j=i+1; j<=N; j++) {    //2nd loop
                if (i+j > 50) {
                    System.out.printf("(%d, %d);", i, j);
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

**Explaination:**
The first loop (`index i`) is going over all of the numbers in allowed range `N`. The second loop (`index j`) is going over all of the other numbers in said range, that are bigger than `i`. We're taking only bigger numbers so we don't go over the same pair twice. Finally only the pairs that are qualified by your condition (bigger than 50) are printed.

*On a side note*: I implore that you work on your "googling" skills. Knowing how to search info online is an [essential](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cEBkvm0-rg0) skill. By a search and a quick read, you could find [links](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-pairs-with-given-sum/) that while not directly solve your problem, does get you a step in the right direction.

**Edit:** Worth noting that I'm not sure this code prints the pairs the exact way you want it to. It also doesn't consider pairs of the same number (e.g. `(26, 26)`). It wasn't clear to me if you're intreseted in these cases or not by your question.